# Drop Cap option in Word 2007 is unavailable (gray'd out)

Tags: word-2007

I've inherited a Word 2007 document from somewhere (dont know the source), where I'm trying to add a Drop Cap to the first paragraph and can't do it. I've found dozens of help sites and articles on how to add a drop cap and understand that it is formatting and framing and how it works and all of that... got it!

I've removed ALL formatting from my text paragraph, even clicked the "remove all formatting" button in a new test paragraph - no good.

I've Drop Capped a test paragraph in a NEW document (that worked), then tried to paste that paragraph into this document - no good.

Any help on how to re-enable the Drop Cap feature? even just for the one paragraph?

thanks,
j

Answer (score 0):

nevermind - I just figured out that the whole document is a GIANT TABLE. Removed the table - no issues.